# Woocommerce short description in meta tag with no plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

How to take product short description and add it here:

```
    <meta name="description" content=" here ">
```

With no use of any plugin as I delete

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

from  in my theme header.php and no plugin works than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WooCommerce product single pages, you will simply use:

```
<?php 
    global $post; 

    if( is_product() ) 
        $short_description = esc_html( $post->post_excerpt );
?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $short_description ?>">
```

Tested and works *(I have commented `wp_head()` like `<?php // wp_head(); ?>` for testing)*.

Comment: Thank you. Great!